# Перенос базы Таблицы из MS SQL в MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Cобственно, вопрос в назании темы. Раз в месяц надо перебрасывать часть данных в Access (связной сервер или через OPENDATASOURCE не рассматривается). Нужно командами чтоб было в автоматическом режиме. Какие варианты есть?

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить ещё один вариант -- утилита BatchAccess умеет импортировать в таблицу MSAccess из файла CSV.

https://rsdn.ru/article/files/progs/BatchAccess.xml

Исходники тоже есть (C#), так что можно допилить до нужной функциональности.

Answer (score 1):

Пишется элементарное приложение на Акцессе, которое без взаимодействия с пользователем копирует данные с SQL сервера куда угодно и завершается, приложение запускается из командной строки, можно по времени планировщиком. При такой схеме никакого взаимодействия с пользователем не требуется

Comment: В условиях было "не использовать линкед сервер"

Comment: Не совсем понятны ограничения. Связанные сервера нельзя, OPENDATASOURCE нельзя, т.е. из хранимой процедуры обращаться нельзя. А что можно? SQL сервер крутится на каком-то сервере, вы можете его использовать не только в качестве хоста для севера базы данных и запустить, например, командный файл вне базы данных? Какие команды вы имеете в виду? Уточните условие.

Answer (score 0):

В комплекте с SQL Server имеется мастер "Import and Export Data" -- это разово, но как я понимаю (не пробовал сам) он позволяет создать из законченного импорта-экспорта SSIS package -- который уже можно запускать сколько угодно раз.

Comment: я ж написал какую-нибуть команду, клацать этот мастер некому будет

Comment: @mamuted а часть про SSIS package вы благополучно пропустили?

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте пакет интеграции SSIS и создайте джоб, который будет запускать пакет когда Вам требуется.